# Add Custom Tabs to the Magento Customer Admin

Tags: magento

I'm working on a new Magneto module.
How can I add a new item to my left menu magento admin panel in customer information with a page that shows some data?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look @ [Add Custom Tabs to the Magento Product Admin](http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin.html)

You will need to update app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customtabs.xml to

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <adminhtml_customer_edit>
     <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
          <name>customer_edit_tab_action</name>
          <block>customertab/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_action</block>
        </action>
     </reference>
  </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

then change the class name accordingly

Also see [How to Add Custom Tabs to Magento Customer Edit page](http://mydons.com/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-magento-customer-edit-page/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply , i already try this solution step by step of mydons but i have magento 1.7.0.2 and she doesnt work

Comment: I found where i add an item to customer tab in app/code/core/mage/adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php 
$this->addTab('wishlist', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Wishlist'),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/wishlist', array('_current' => true)),
            ));
but i dont know how to show my content